# Global variable is not defined error

Tags: python, dictionary, geolocation, web-crawler

I have tried to implement the code for streaming tweets based on geolocation and got the code for same but i am constantly getting the error as 
"global name 'requestid' is not defined."
The code written is as given below:

```
# Geolocation twitter crawler using streaming API
import os
import sys
import math
import time
from datetime import datetime
import simplejson as json
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from geopy import geocoders

adress = str(sys.argv[1])  # Location (City name, adress...)
halfradius = float(sys.argv[2])  # Radius in Km of the Bounding Box
outputlocation = str(sys.argv[3])
datereq = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%d%m%Y")
access_token = "749913608-Z9LiTN6xv7PluHoyNn3Ggot4rnkGObr2OVZsmv5i"
access_token_secret = "wKK0BWG1dXdNBKAVPCeasbtqQI4W3Vf0jCusRIhu6LKla"
consumer_key = "f9CE9GjsMCioQ8NnTEJXn4IxE"
consumer_secret = "a53Ro5lCnsYG6Lq0jW3J6ulEMzy3HQYKknRqUnvdhJFdbsPAuy"


class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        data = json.loads(data)
        logfile = open(os.path.join(outputlocation, adress + "-" + datereq + "-
Request" + str(requestid) + ".csv"), "a")

        tweet_date = unicode(data['created_at']).encode("ascii", "ignore")[:10] + " " + unicode(data['created_at']).encode("ascii", "ignore")[-4:]
        tweet_time = unicode(data['created_at']).encode("ascii", "ignore")[11:-11]
        user_id = unicode(data['user']['id']).encode("ascii", "ignore")
        text_id = unicode(data['id']).encode("ascii", "ignore")
        user_location = unicode(data['user']
['location']).encode("ascii", "ignore")

        user_lang = unicode(data['user']['lang']).encode("ascii", "ignore")
        text_msg = unicode(data['text']).encode("utf8", "ignore").replace(',', ' ')

        if data['coordinates'] == None :
            # print >>logfile, '[No geotag for this tweet]'
            print '[No geotag for this tweet]'
            longitude = ""
            latitude = ""

        else:
            coord = unicode(data['coordinates']['coordinates']).encode("ascii", "ignore")
            longitude = coord[:coord.rfind(',')].replace("[", "")
            latitude = coord.split(" ")[1].replace("]", "")
            stream_log = longitude + "," + latitude + "," + tweet_date + "," + tweet_time + "," + user_id + "," + user_location + "," + user_lang + "," + text_id + "," + text_msg
            stream_log = stream_log.replace('\n', ' ')
            print stream_log
            print >> logfile, stream_log
        logfile.close()
        return True

    def on_error(self, statut):
        print statut

# degrees to radians
def deg2rad(degrees):
    return math.pi * degrees / 180.0

# radians to degrees
def rad2deg(radians):
    return 180.0 * radians / math.pi

# Semi-axes of WGS-84 geoidal reference
WGS84_a = 6378137.0  # Major semiaxis [m]
WGS84_b = 6356752.3  # Minor semiaxis [m]

# Earth radius at a given latitude, according to the WGS-84 ellipsoid [m]
def WGS84EarthRadius(lat):
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius
    An = WGS84_a * WGS84_a * math.cos(lat)
    Bn = WGS84_b * WGS84_b * math.sin(lat)
    Ad = WGS84_a * math.cos(lat)
    Bd = WGS84_b * math.sin(lat)
    return math.sqrt((An * An + Bn * Bn) / (Ad * Ad + Bd * Bd))

# Bounding box surrounding the point at given coordinates,
# assuming local approximation of Earth surface as a sphere
# of radius given by WGS84
def boundingBox(latitudeInDegrees, longitudeInDegrees, halfSideInKm):
    lat = deg2rad(latitudeInDegrees)
    lon = deg2rad(longitudeInDegrees)
    halfSide = 1000 * halfSideInKm

    # Radius of Earth at given latitude
    radius = WGS84EarthRadius(lat)

    # Radius of the parallel at given latitude
    pradius = radius * math.cos(lat)
    latMin = lat - halfSide / radius
    latMax = lat + halfSide / radius
    lonMin = lon - halfSide / pradius
    lonMax = lon + halfSide / pradius
    return (rad2deg(latMin), rad2deg(lonMin), rad2deg(latMax), rad2deg(lonMax))

def main():
    g = geocoders.GoogleV3()
    place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(adress)
    location = [boundingBox(lng, lat, halfradius)
[0], boundingBox(lng, lat, halfradius)[1], boundingBox(lng, lat, halfradius)[2], boundingBox(lng, lat, halfradius)[3]]

    # print "Location of "+ adress+" :",lng,lat
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
    twitterStream.filter(locations=location)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

requestid is not defined as indicated. I know nothing about this code; however, is requestid bundled in the received JSON packet? If so, extract it from same before using it to build your csv filename in the on_data(...) method.